# How to recover from database errors in Grails within a transaction

Tags: exception, grails, transactions, grails-orm

In short, what I am trying solve is how to recover from certain database errors in a Grails application using Hibernate and continue on with the transaction skipping over the failed row updates that are part of a batch of changes.

The application uses Grails 2.3.11 but I have also tried with version 1.3.8 with similar failed results.

Basically there is a Grails service class that iterates over a list of imported records and attempts to update associated master records appropriately. In certain situations exceptions might occur during the *`domain.save(flush:true)`* call e.g. *`org.hibernate.exception.DataException`* thrown due to issues like (Data truncation: Data too long for column ...).

At this point I have tried:

- Disabling transactions
- Using *domainObj.withTransaction()* for each individual record
- Trying various @Transactional annotations
- Calling *domain.clearErrors()* and *domain.discard()* after catching the exception
- Tried using a nested service with Transactional annotation with *noRollbackFor* as shown below
- A number of other approaches but nothing I've tried has worked

Example code:

```
@Transactional
class UpdateService {
    public updateBatch(Integer batchId) {
       ...
       list.each { record -> 
           record.value = 123
           try {
              nestedService.saveDomain()
           } catch (e) {
              record.clearErrors()
              record.discard()
           }
       }
       batch.status = "POSTED"
       batch.save()
   }
}

@Transactional
class NestedService {

   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
   public void saveDomain(domainObj) throws RuntimeException {
       if (domainObj.validate() && domainObj.save(flush:true) {
           log.info "domain $domain was saved"
       }
   }
}
```

Once an error occurs I can't seem to clear out the hibernate session. On each subsequent record being updated I receive the error:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction
```

where it indicates the original failed domain id.

---

Revision:

Vahid, Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried that. I realized one issue is that I am passing objects across transactional boundaries. So I experimented with the NestedService class do something along the lines of:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRE_NEW)
public void saveDomain(domainObj) {
   def newObj = new Domain.get(domainObj.id)
   newObj.properties = domainObj.properties
   if (newObj.validate() && newObj.save(force:true) ) { ... }
```

I expected that to work but the original domainObj still fails even though I'm not calling the save on it. Very strange...

Comment: tried REQUIRES_NEW for your propagation ? I put some notes up about acid here https://github.com/vahidhedayati/documentation/blob/master/grails/acid.md recently reading this http://blog.perezalcolea.info/2014/06/09/Grails-Transactions-Revisited.html and this http://sacharya.com/transactions-in-grails/

Comment: Vahid - please see my comment in the original comments where I added a revision.

Comment: what if you tried newObj.merge() before the validate and save, also did you manage to read the last part of the 3rd link about batch processing in hibernate. Would never recommend it for Controllers though. If you have time https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNey9T--rLE watch Burt explains transactions really well. Need to watch it a few times more myself.

Comment: @JohnMartin Is this the actual code? Because you have method 'saveDomain(domainObj)' but you have called only 'nestedService.saveDomain()' without argument in previous part. And in revision part, you are doing 'new Domain.get' where 'new' is needed. And 'force:true' instead of 'flush:true'.

Comment: @Ramsharan - I was mocking up the code so it doesn't surprise me that there were a couple of typos.

Comment: @Vahid - I had run across blog post that you referred to. I've been noodling on that and think that the solution to my problem is to disable the Grails automatic transactions and roll-my-own using the techniques described in the blog post. I'll follow up after I have a solution.

One of my issues with the Transactional is that the_ noRollbackFor_ does not work as I had expected. I need to work up example app and potentially report it as a bug.

Comment: @JohnMartin did you ever manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to loop and then use validate(). If it does fail,  then just store the id of the failed entity and proceed.

```
if(!domainObject.validate()){
    // store Id for trying it again later ?
}else{
    // Save
}
```

Comment: The issue I have is that it gets by the current domain constraints so validate() returns true. The issue is that the save() fails and automatically rolls back the entire transaction regardless of the noRollbackFor annotation. Once the error occurs every subsequent update fails. It is rather strange...

Comment: If you are using the Transactional Annotation on an Action/Function level, then try not to use it at the Service definition( Set it to being false ). By default all services are transational, so you don't have to explicitly define it as being Transactional. Have a look at the Grails Services section of the [http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/services.html].